# docusign - sending an envelope using signing groups custom button

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

From [this](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/signing-group-custom-buttons) official docusign support guide, I understood that we don't need to add `Email` or `FirstName` or `LastName` atrributes in `CRL` call when `SigningGroup` is used. My custom button url in salesforce is below.

```
/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID=a3G4C000000HE8X&
CRL=SigningGroup~LegalSigner;RoutingOrder~20;Role~Signer5
&OCO=Send
```

When I try to send a document, I get the following exception:

> Error: System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
>   returned a SOAP Fault: The email address for the recipient is invalid.
>   The recipient Id follows. faultcode=soap:Client
>   faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx

The error says that the email address is invalid, because I did not pass one in the `CRL` parameter.

Anyone have an idea on what is wrong with my custom button url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to docusign professional service team today and guess what? We need to upgrade our docusign installed package version in the org. (upgraded from 6.3 to 6.7.2)

[This](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-migrate-Docusign-for-Salesforce-to-the-latest-version) document from docusign website says

> Future updates will be downloaded and installed automatically.

Wondering why it never got upgraded automatically for us. While the error message is so mis-leading, please check your version package number before you start using any new functionality that is released. Lesson Learned.